# Can't get TEMPLATE_DIR correct working path

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

Good evening,

I've read multiple answers from Stack Overflow, from several tutorials and still, it doesn't work.

The project is called "crepes_bretonnes".
The absolute path of the project is : 
`/Users/Jack/Desktop/Projet_Django/crepes_bretonnes`

This path leads to the project's root which contains :

- blog
- crepes_bretonnes
- db.sqlite3
- manage.py
- static
- templates

`settings.py` is in the second folder : `crepes_bretonnes` and contains :

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

If I did things properly : Setting_Dir is the path of the `Settings.py` and to go back to the root path (one level up) I use the function `pardir`

So now, Django will be searching templates in the templates folder at the root of the crepes_bretonnes project at the following path : 
`/Users/Jack/Desktop/Projet_Django/crepes_bretonnes`

A function in the `views.py`of the `blog` app return a `render'  containing a template :

`return render(request, 'blog/addition.html', locals())`

This template is located in a template folder in the blog folder.

First line of the `addition.html` is :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

This base.html is contained in the root folder called templates. I don't understand why it keeps me giving the following error:

> Django tried loading these templates, in this order: Using loader
>   django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: Using loader
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html
>   (File does not exist)
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Django-1.8.3-py3.4.egg/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html
>   (File does not exist)
>   /Users/Jack/Desktop/Projet_Django/crepes_bretonnes/blog/templates/base.html
>   (File does not exist)

Actually it can't find the base.html in the templates folder at the root of my project. There is something critical about absolute path I must be missing at some point.

Could you help ?

EDIT : I'm using Mac os X. 
Here are all the printed path requested in the settings.py :

```
**Base_Dir** /Users/Jack/Desktop/Projet_Django/crepes_bretonnes

**Settings_Dir** /Users/Jack/Desktop/Projet_Django/crepes_bretonnes/crepes_bretonnes

**Project_Path** /Users/Jack/Desktop/Projet_Django/crepes_bretonnes

**Templates_Dir** /Users/Jack/Desktop/Projet_Django/crepes_bretonnes/templates
```

EDIT : ANSWER

Modify `settings.py` in order to make it look like this :

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? What is the result of `os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official Django documentation the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting is deprecated as of Django 1.8 and they recommend using the DIRS settings instead.

Also if you have template files within your apps make sure that the APP_DIRS is set to True because it defaults to False.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs